# How to evenly distribute same size holes across a stretched surface

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I need to make an object for a 3d printing project. The object needs to let water pass but block out bigger things like leaves and small pine cones. I already have the basic shape down, but i am struggling with getting evenly spaced, holes that are the same size.

I have tried using a particle system but it looks like you can't boolean a particle system.
Here is a picture of the shape i need holes cut into. The rectangles were my attempt at cutting with the particle system.

[image]

Does anyone know how i can achieve evenly spaced holes that are all the same size?

Comment: You can boolean cut the particle system. Convert it to real mesh object (convert in the Modifiers stack, remove system, then join resulting objects). As there aren't too many particles it likely won't freeze for an hour or something. Then pick that object as Boolean cutter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try instancing for this.

1. Reduce the object to a profile
2. Parent the cutting shape, set instancing to Faces
3. Add the Screw modifier and adjust it to your needs.

Then just go *Object > Apply > Make instances real* and use Boolean...

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks, I had no idea you could bind an object to faces like that.

Answer (score 9):

You could model this:

[image]

1. Establish Basic geometry, (mine is an extruded half round-cube) and reserve a highly-subdivided copy, you're going to shrinkwrap to it later
2. <kbd>X</kbd> Delete > *Only Faces*
3. Edge Menu *> Subdivide*

[image]

4. <kbd>F</kbd> refill the faces, and Face Menu > *Poke* them
5. Select one of the new vertices, and  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar > Number of Connecting Edges*. Deselect the ones you don't want to be holes.
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel the remaining
   selected vertices, with an offset. Note the offset setting.

You can use the shipped add-on *Loop Tools > Circle* if necessary, to round the holes to a dimension slightly smaller than the bevel offset you noted. Delete the hole faces. Now you use the *Srinkwrap* modifier targeted on your reserved intact copy to ensure the surface has not been distorted by the edge subdivision, poking, etc, and apply it.

The rest is modifiers: *Solidify*, *Bevel* (by angle), *Subdivision Surface*...

[image]

Comment: That produces a remarkably clean mesh, I will have to study these selection tools further.
However this also falls prey to the same issue i was experiencing in that the spacing of the holes get further apart when the width of the object increases.

Comment: I don't mean to spam all your posts, but this is a really smart way to do it :). Way more elegant than some ugly boolean...

Comment: @JachymMichal Would you be willing to explain to me why everyone hates booleans so much? They seem pretty useful to me.

Comment: @Michael Well, they can create ugly topology if you're not careful :). But it's often more of a virtue signaling "Hey, I hate booleans, that means I'm a pro". If you can use them, more power to you :).

Comment: Nothing wrong with Booleans, IMO, so long as they're not a lazy, bad-topo, alternative to cleaner (and sometimes _quicker_), modelling. Especially if the meshes don't need to deform, have exquisite normals, or to be kept as low-poly as possible. 3D printing doesn't need to fuss about those things.